# Svelte on:keydown how to do it in right way

Tags: svelte

I have this code

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    {#each items as item}
      <li
        tabindex="0"
        on:click={() => dispatch("tabChange", item)}
        on:keydown={() => dispatch("tabChange", item)}
      >
        <div class:active={item === activeItem}>{item}</div>
      </li>
    {/each}
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I call it from here

```
<Tabs {activeItem} {items} on:tabChange={tabChange} />
```

I expected, when I click on li element or click on any button, It will switch tabs. But it isn't. Why?

tabindex="0"
button and etc.
But it's all about bad solution I think.

Comment: Use a `button` or `a` element instead of adding `on:keydown`, see [this](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/8001).

Comment: You have not shown any code that actually tries to change the tab, i.e. the event handler.

Comment: when/where is `activeItem`-variable **updated** with the new selected value?

Comment: I copied your code into a Svelte REPL, seems to work fine

https://svelte.dev/repl/1c4b69d4e355485ebf19a290ec93ca18?version=4.2.0